# How to find out the (using XCTest UITest) a cell that has a focus in a table view in tvOS AppleTV?

Tags: xcode, swift, tvos, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to automate UI tests of an app on Apple TV (tvOS).

On the login screen I select the 'enter username' field. Then the screen with previously used logins appears. On the screen I would like to select 'clear all' cell.

To clarify: the "Previously Used" menu seems to be built-in in the tvOS and it might appear automatically whenever someone selects User name textfield in a login menu. I'm unsure about that, so still I need to confirm that information.

[image]

So I thought the code like this would be a solution:

```
    if self.app.staticTexts["Previously Used"].exists {

        let clearAllCell = self.app.cells.staticTexts["Clear All"]

        while clearAllCell.hasFocus == false {
            XCUIRemote.sharedRemote().pressButton(.Down)
            sleep(1)
        }

        XCUIRemote.sharedRemote().pressButton(.Select)
    }
```

however even in a state like this:

[image]

the properties `hasFocus` and `selected` of the cell seem to return false:

```
po self.app.cells.staticTexts["Clear All"].hasFocus
po self.app.cells.staticTexts["Clear All"].selected
```

[image]

How to find the "Clear All" cell when it has "focused state"?

UPDATE:

I've tried the solution proposed by @Oletha, but with no success. `clearAllCell.hasFocus` unfortunately seems to return always false.

```
    if self.app.staticTexts["Previously Used"].exists {

        let clearAllCell = self.app.cells.staticTexts["Clear All"]

        let predicateHasFocus = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true", argumentArray: nil)

        expectationForPredicate(predicateHasFocus, evaluatedWithObject: clearAllCell, handler: { () -> Bool in
            if clearAllCell.hasFocus {
                return true
            } else {
                sleep(1)
                XCUIRemote.sharedRemote().pressButton(.Down)
                return false
            }
        })

        waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(10, handler: nil)

        XCUIRemote.sharedRemote().pressButton(.Select)
    }
```

UPDATE:

A non-elegant solution at the moment is to:

```
    if self.app.staticTexts["Previously Used"].exists {
        var cellsCount = self.app.cells.count

        // Select Clear All menu button, hack as it was not possible to detect "Clear All" cell in another way
        while cellsCount > 0 {
            sleep(1)
            XCUIRemote.sharedRemote().pressButton(.Down)
            cellsCount -= 1
        }

        sleep(1)
        XCUIRemote.sharedRemote().pressButton(.Up)
        sleep(1)
        XCUIRemote.sharedRemote().pressButton(.Select)
    }
```

Comment: Does accessing the static text directly make a difference? e.g. `app.staticTexts["Clear All"].hasFocus`

Comment: Unfortunately no, `po app.staticTexts["Clear All"].hasFocus` and `po app.staticTexts["Clear All"].selected` still return false.

Comment: Hmm. Why are they cells in the first place? Can they easily be migrated to buttons? I have an app that uses buttons and `hasFocus` without issue.

Comment: I think the whole menu "Previously used" is native to tvOS, so there might be no easy way to migrate to buttons. I have tried `po app.buttons.staticTexts["Clear All"].exists` but it returns false.

Comment: This looks like a problem I had where the cell itself was an accessibility element, so its descendants weren't visible to the inspectors. Have you tried putting an accessibilityIdentifier on the cell itself and calling it as app.cells["<identifier"] ?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this "Previously Used" menu seems to be built-in in the tvOS and it might appear automatically whenever someone selects User name textfield in the app menu. That's the reason why I don't have much control over the menu like I am unable to set the identifiers and so on.

Comment: Interesting. Can you override it, I wonder? I can't find any documentation in it, sadly.

Comment: @Aaron Sofaer I'm starting to suspect that this might be some kind of overlook in tvOS or XCTest framework.

Comment: @tommagellancook What is the state of the Clear All button, as far as you can see? Please could stop the test on a breakpoint where it is in the same state as in your screenshot above, and post the results of: `.exists`, `.label` and `.hasFocus` for the Clear All button?

Comment: @Oletha thanks. Here it the result: http://imgur.com/bPZWwy1

Comment: @tommagellancook Thanks. There's something not right about the debug output for hasFocus - it's logging that it's pressing the down button. This shouldn't happen as part of determining focus... Is clearAllCell an XCUIElement?

Comment: @Oletha `po app.cells.staticTexts["Clear All"].elementType` results in `__C.XCUIElementType`, similarly `po app.cells.staticTexts["Clear All"].isKindOfClass(XCUIElement)` results in `true`. I too did notice the button press there, seems odd. I've tested it using your code snippet.

Comment: @tommagellancook It looked like the whole expectationForPredicate ran when you did po clearAllCell.hasFocus... Strange. Can you try the same set of properties as print() statements before and after the expectation, and use breakpoints to follow the code path that's being taken all the way through to the test failure?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems with my app and found 2 things helpful to write running UI tests:

1. Always make an 1 second delay after every remote button press, because the assert evaluation is often faster than the focus change and therefore returns `false`

   ```
   XCUIRemote.sharedRemote().pressButton(.Down)
   sleep(1)
   ```
2. Look up the the exact UI hierarchy position of your focused element. For example `print(XCUIApplication().debugDescription)` will give you an detailed UI tree and makes it easy to access your element properly.

[image]

This assert has returned true:

```
    XCTAssert(XCUIApplication().tabBars.buttons["Home"].hasFocus)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `expectationForPredicate` and `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout` to check if the cell has focus. Using expectations causes the accessibility hierarchy snapshot to be refreshed for each time the check occurs. Your while loop is checking against the same cached hierarchy snapshot every time, so the result won't change.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let clearAllCell = app.cells.staticTexts["Clear All"]
let focusedPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
let remote = XCUIRemote.sharedRemote()

expectationForPredicate(focusedPredicate, evaluatedWithObject: clearAllCell, handler: {() -> Bool in
    // Check if the cell has focus
    if clearAllCell.hasFocus {
        // Fulfill the expectation
        return true
    } else {
        // Move down one cell before the next check
        remote.pressButton(.Down)
        return false
    }
})
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5, handler: nil)

remote.pressButton(.Select)
```

`XCUIRemote.sharedRemote()` didn't actually work for me, but I'd guess this is working for you - I've not got an Apple TV app to test with.

Comment: Could you provide code example by refactoring my unsuccessful solution from the question? I've tried to do it using `expectationForPredicate` and `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout`, but with no success.

Comment: @tommagellancook Updated the answer with an example that I think should help.

Comment: I've tried your code, but it looks like it doesn't work as it should be. The loop is checking if clearAll has the focus, but it never returns true. I've updated my question so you could peak inside the code.

Answer (score 0):

first of all it's a native screen in tvOS So all the suggestions related to try and set accessibility ids are not relevant. Tryi to put a breakpoint when you reach that screen and print out which element is focused

I believe the answer will be. A position on screen. Or cell without identifier. I'm struggling with Same issues on Apple TV and would like to know about all the problems you have since I wonder how mature xcuitest is for tvOS